# Alter table based on query result without using procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement

I am getting the result as "True" or "False" from the below query.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.counter>=1 THEN 'True'

                               ELSE 'False' END AS isUserAuthorised
                               FROM (SELECT Count(*) as counter FROM information_schema.statistics
                                    WHERE  table_name = 'tblechecklistcustomer' AND index_name = 'index_Cust') a;

I want to execute the below query if the above query result  is "True"

ALTER TABLE tblechecklistcustomer DROP INDEX index_Cust;
```

How can i Do it in a single query / using if codition without using stored procedure 
I tried this way

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN a.counter>=1 THEN 'True'
                               ELSE 'False' END AS isUserAuthorised
                               FROM (SELECT Count(*) as counter FROM information_schema.statistics
                                    WHERE  table_name = 'tblechecklistcustomer' AND index_name = 'index_Cust') a)=='True')
                                   then ALTER TABLE tblechecklistcustomer DROP INDEX index_Cust;
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. DDL statements can't be put inside SELECT queries.

Comment: @Barmar If I Write procedure, can I do it without using a variable if so how can i do it.

Comment: In a procedure I think you would be able to use an `IF` statement that checked `a.counter` and the result of the `SELECT COUNT(*)` subquery, with the `ALTER` statement in the `THEN` clause. However, I'm not very experienced at writing mysql procedures.

Comment: For the love of bits, why?

Answer (score 1):

With the following structure:

```sql
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tblechecklistcustomer`;

CREATE TABLE `tblechecklistcustomer` (
  `cust` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `index_cust` (`cust`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

With stored procedure can be something like:

```sql
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`()
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                FROM
                    `information_schema`.`statistics`
                WHERE
                    `table_schema` = DATABASE() AND
                    `table_name` = 'tblechecklistcustomer' AND
                    `index_name` = 'index_cust') THEN
        ALTER TABLE `tblechecklistcustomer` DROP INDEX `index_cust`;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Without a stored procedure you can try something like:

```sql
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN `a`.`counter` >= 1 THEN TRUE
        ELSE FALSE
    END INTO @`counter`
FROM (SELECT @`counter` := NULL) `der`,
    (SELECT COUNT(0) AS `counter`
        FROM
            `information_schema`.`statistics`
        WHERE
            `table_schema` = DATABASE() AND
            `table_name` = 'tblechecklistcustomer' AND
            `index_name` = 'index_cust') `a`;
SET @`alter` := 'ALTER TABLE `tblechecklistcustomer` DROP INDEX `index_cust`'; 
SET @`nothing` := 'DO (SELECT NULL)';
SET @`stmt` := IF(@`counter`, @`alter`, @`nothing`);
PREPARE `exec` FROM @`stmt`;
EXECUTE `exec`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `exec`;
```